# MVVM and DataGrid View re-use as embedded controls within otherviews with subset data

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Okay here's the situation. Net 4 WPF NO Silverlight.

I have several Views that present a datagrid showing the contents of some observable collections e.g.

```
ObservableCollection<ClassAViewModel> sourceA;
ObservableCollection<ClassBViewModel> sourceB;
ObservableCollection<ClassCViewModel> sourceC;
```

The collections are populated by a call to the data access layer. I can display this data easily enough with a Usercontrol that contains a datagrid bound to the appropriate collection. 
I have

- `ClassAView` and `ClassAViewModel` to
  control display of single `ClassA`
  data,
- `ClassBView` and `ClassBViewModel` to
  control display of single `ClassB` data
- `ClassCView` and `ClassCViewModel` to
  control display of single `ClassC` data

I also have:

- `AllClassAView` and `AllClassAViewModel`
  to display a DataGrid with data
  relating to all `ClassA` instances.
- `AllClassBView` and `AllClassBViewModel`
  to display a DataGrid with data
  relating to all `ClassB` instances.

  etc.

Now say that `ClassA` contains a subset of the `ClassB` collection and a subset of the `ClassC` collection etc.

In my resource file I have bound the ViewModels and their Views together in the following manner (vm and vw are the namespaces of where they are) :

```
<DataTemplate DataType="x:Type vm:ClassAViewModel}">
  <vw:ClassAView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now what I was hoping to do was use an `AllClassBView` or `AllClassBViewModel` within the `ClassAView` to display the subset of `ClassB` instances that relate to it.

What is the best way to call up this data?

Can I re-use the `AllClassBView` UserControl to display a subset of the `ClassB` ObservableCollection and what is the best way of doing this?

I don't want to place any code within the *ClassAView.cs* file only within the *ClassAView.xaml* or *ClassAViewModel*.

Should I just add a new property to the AllClassBView and use that to filter the list? For example within ClassBViewModel where I generate the list of ClassBViewModels (for use in the DataGrid) I can use:

```
if(this.ClassA_Id!=0)
{
  List<ClassBViewModel> all = (from ClassB in this.DataRepository.GetClassBs().Where(x=>x.ClassA_Id == this.ClassA_Id) select new ClassBViewModel()).ToList();
}
else
{
  List<ClassBViewModel> all = (from ClassB in this.DataRepository.GetClassBs() select new ClassBViewModel()).ToList();
}

this.sourceB= new ObservableCollection<ClassBViewModel>(all);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've cracked it.

My problem may not have come across as very clear.

Whether my solution is good practice or not I don't know.

What I have done is as follows:

I placed an extra property into the `AllClassBViewModel` that allows me to filter its list of `ClassBViewModels` to those that relate to `ClassA`.

```
public ulong ClassA_Id{get;set;}
```

So now when the `AllClassBViewModel` builds its list of `ClassBViewModels` it can now filter them by:

```
if(this.ClassA_Id!=0)
{
  List<ClassBViewModel> all = (from ClassB in this.DataRepository.GetClassBs().Where(x=>x.ClassA_Id == this.ClassA_Id) select new ClassBViewModel()).ToList();
}
else
{
  List<ClassBViewModel> all = (from ClassB in this.DataRepository.GetClassBs() select new ClassBViewModel()).ToList();
}

this.sourceB= new ObservableCollection<ClassBViewModel>(all);
```

I added a property and field to my ClassAViewModel that were of the AllClassBViewModel type.

```
private AllClassBViewModel fieldAllClassBViewModel;
public AllClassBViewModel AllClassBVM{get{return this.fieldAllClassBViewModel;}}
```

I then added an entry to an `AllClassBView` into the `ClassAView` that had a data context bound to the `AllClassBVM` property within `ClassAViewModel`.

```
<vw:AllClassBView DataContext="{Binding AllClassBVM}"/>
```

No all I have to do is check through the command binding.